# Was bedeutet hier „bei“? Kann es durch „mit“ ersetzt werden?

Tags: meaning

> Bei guten Autos sind wir im vorn.

Ist es falsch, wenn ich *bei* durch *mit* ersetze?

Ich verstehe die Bedeutung von *bei*, nicht nur in diesem Satz, sondern in mehreren Sätzen nicht.

Comment: There is a mistake in that sentence. Where did you get it from? Could it be: *Bei guten Autos sind wir vorn* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Mit* bedeutet entweder *unter Verwendung von* oder *zusammen mit.* Du hast anstelle des Satzes in der Frage folgende Alternative vorgeschlagen:

> Mit guten Autos sind wir vorn

Diese bedeutet entweder, dass wir gute Autos verwenden, um Vorne zu liegen (das wäre eine Aussage, wie sie zum Beispiel [Sebastian Vettel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebastian_Vettel) tätigen könnte), oder aber, dass wir in einem Rennen uns den ersten Platz mit den guten Autos teilen. Beide Bedeutungen sind aber nicht gewünscht, deswegen kann *bei* hier **nicht** durch *mit* ersetzt werden.

---

> Bei guten Autos sind wir vorn.

*Bei* kann eine Reihe von Bedeutungen tragen; unter Anderem auch *neben;* gemeint ist hier aber die Bedeutung *was … betrifft.* Der Satz ist also so zu verstehen, dass wir in der Herstellung von guten Autos vorne sind; wobei mit »vorne« ein abstraktes, wirtschaftliches »Vorne« gemeint ist.

Answer (score 0):

In sentences like:

> Bei guten Autos sind wir vorn.
>
> Beim (=bei + dem) Essen bin ich eher der traditionelle Typ.
>
> Bei gutem Wetter gehen wir ins Freibad.

, the meaning of *bei* is

```
as far as ... is concerned
```

or

```
in case of...
```

So these examples could be translated with:

> Concerning good cars we are ahead (in the first row)

(could be a slogan of a car manufacturer), and

> As far as food is concerned, I am rather traditional.
>
> In case of good weather we go to the open-air pool.

And no, you cannot replace *bei* with *mit* here.